# Efficient way for storing predefined objects in android?

Tags: java, android, json, xml

If I would like to have a list of objects of the same class, but with different data in their members what would be the best approach to load the data? These are all defined by the developer and none of it is added by the user. I do, however, want the ability to easily add more objects to the program.

Here's an example to clarify what I've said above:
Say I have a class Fruit with members: color, average amount of vitamin c, image of fruit. I also have a list of fruit objects that I've come up with: banana, peach, orange. I know what the members of these should be for each fruit ahead of time. I would like to display to the user each fruit and its attributes. As a developer, I would also like to have the ability to define more fruits easily if I find out I need more.

I was thinking of using either JSON or XML, parsing through the data, and using a loop to add these objects to an array, but was wondering if this is a good approach.

Comment: `JSON` is quite handy and very efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many items the list will have - you can choose either JSON or SQLLite DB.  If the number of items in the list is going to be very high - say few hundres or even thousands, then, saving them in SQLLite DB will be useful - as you can use CursorAdapter or equivalent to create your list views.  If you use JSON, then, you will end up loading whole of jSON array in memory before constructing your list view.

I am not big fan of XML in Android.  The reason being though it is easing to convert JSON to POJO in Android, I found it difficult to parse XMLs in Android in a developer-friendly manner.